# update query not working in prepared statement with multiple where clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following update statement which does execute successfully but with no value change in the table.

```
 $name = "John Doe"; //to update into John Stack
 $chenna = "Mz"; $reg = 25; $km = 3;
 $dbh = PDO Object

 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `hl_customer` SET `name`=:hming, `address`=:chenna
         WHERE `regd`=:regd AND `kum`=:km");
 $stmt->bindParam(':hming', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':chenna', $hmun, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindParam(':regd', $reg, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $stmt->bindParam(':km', $km, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $stmt->execute();
 $affected = $stmt->rowCount();
```

Another tested code:

```
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `hl_customer` SET `name`=?, `address`=?
         WHERE `regd`=? AND `kum`=?");
 $stmt->execute([$name, $hmun, $reg, $km]);
 $affected = $stmt->rowCount();

 $stmt = $dbh->query("UPDATE `hl_customer` SET `name`='$name', `address`='$chenna'
         WHERE `regd`='$reg' AND `kum`='$km'");
```

In order to update I kept changing the `$name` variable, yet there was no affected row. The row count always return 0. I did tested in both phpmyadmin(latest version) and mysql Workbench(latest) and the problem is still there. Then I tested again in mysql console, and it works as expected. But why is it not working in the code shown above, phpmyadmin and workbench. What could be the problem? Is my code wrong? I used mysql 8.0.12, php 5.6.* and php 7.1.*.
I did test it again without parameterized query, still it did not work. Now I begin to think that it is a kind of bug in php.
Thanks

Comment: Do any value changed? If the valued doesn't change, the PDO driver will return 0 row affected.

Comment: No the value did not change. It changed only when i did the update via mysql console.

Comment: What happens if you removing the binds and pass the variables directly in the execute call? `$stmt->execute([':hming'=>$name,
                 ':chenna'=>$hmun,
   ':regd'=>$reg,
   ':km'=>$km]);`

Comment: Directly or indirectly the result is the same. Initially I thought my code was wrong. It works only when I remove `and kum:km` from the where clause.

Comment: @MawiaHL then you don't have a row in `hl_customer` table where  regd = 25 AND kum = 3. I just tried this locally with mariadb 5 and php 7.1.23 and it worked just fine. I was able to get it to reproduce your result when the values for regd and hum fields did not exist in the table. This is a data problem. Try doing a select with the same where clauses and see what rows appear.

Comment: See it does not change the value of `name` even in work bench and phpmyadmin. I do have reg=25 and kum=3 in my table.

Comment: UPDATE hl_customer SET name='',address=''
         WHERE regd =  AND kum = 
now set values correctly and run directly on database check the result

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't see anything wrong with your code try and verify if the number of columns in your table matches the number of paramaters you have because you said it works when you drop the last parameter

Comment: But why does it work in mysql console while it does not in php? I want to use the last parameter.

Comment: @MawiaHL it could be a data problem i had the same problem with java and when nothing resolved it i dropped the database and remodeled it